# Spring-Cloud-Zipkin runs incorrectly about 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

Tags: zipkin

I am new in spring-cloud.My projects are about spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-eureka, spring-cloud-zipkin,I am running projects locally and it is normal.When I put my projects in Ubuntu, the project 'spring-cloud-zipkin' runs incorrectly. The error is about 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException', thanks for your answer very much. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEDK5.png)

and my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfmdV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C5B6.png)

in the pom.xml:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3bPy.png)

Answer (score 0):

I dont kown can you see my pic and I put my code:

**pom.xml:**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.test.itoken.zipkin.ZipKinApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**ZipkinApplication.java:**

```
package com.test.itoken.zipkin;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import zipkin.server.internal.EnableZipkinServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZipkinServer
public class ZipkinApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZipkinApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**The error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.itoken.zipkin.ZipKinApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```